# Is my solution correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Find a basis and its size for $U=\{{(x,y,z)}\in R^{3};3x-y-z=0\}$"

My response:$$3x-y-z=0\Longrightarrow y=3x-z$$$$(x,y,z)=(x,3y-z,z)$$Making $x$ and $z$ equals zero, one at a time, we have$$x=0\Longrightarrow(0,-z,z)$$$$z=0\Longrightarrow(x,3x,0)$$Adding these results:$$(0,-z,z)+(x,3x,0)=z(0,-1,1)+x(1,3,0)$$Thus, a base is$$\{(0,-1,1),(1,3,0)\}$$And the size is $$\dim 2.$$
$$$$
*Is this solution correct?*

Comment: Well that equation gives a plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$ so the dimension is indeed $2$. That also indeed appears to be a basis.

Comment: Yes, this is correct (but you have a typo at one place: $3y-z$ should be $3x-z$). Also, I would choose other names for the parameters.

Comment: Tank you... Two